# Replace in one step based on matched result

Tags: php, regex, date, replace, preg-replace

I have a string and I want each `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` date time string to be replaced with a unix timestamp.

I have managed to get as far as identifying where date time strings occur:

```
$my_string = 'Hello world 2014-12-25 10:00:00 and foo 2014-09-10 05:00:00, bar';

preg_match_all('((?:2|1)\\d{3}(?:-|\\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(?:-|\\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[1-2][0-9])|(?:3[0-1]))(?:T|\\s)(?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:2[0-3])):(?:[0-5][0-9]):(?:[0-5][0-9]))',$my_string,$my_matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

print_r($my_matches);
```

This outputs an array of arrays containing the value of the date time string that was matched and its location:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2014-12-25 10:00:00
                    [1] => 12
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2014-09-10 05:00:00
                    [1] => 40
                )

        )

)
```

From this point I was going to loop through the arrays and replace based on `str_replace()` and `strtotime()` however I'm thinking it would have lower execution time if I could do something like this:

```
$my_string = preg_replace(
    '((?:2|1)\\d{3}(?:-|\\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(?:-|\\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[1-2][0-9])|(?:3[0-1]))(?:T|\\s)(?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:2[0-3])):(?:[0-5][0-9]):(?:[0-5][0-9]))',
    strtotime($VALUE_OF_MATCHED_STRING),
    $my_string
);
```

So that every found instance of the matched would simply be made to `strtotime()` format.

What is the correct way to get this result? Is looping the most feasible way?

Comment: +1 for a clear, readable, correctly formatted question (You won't see many such questions in [tag:php]) ;)

Comment: Thanks @AmalMurali, I'm hoping if I put a bit of thought in to the question then it'll mean less thought for a valuable answer. You've proved that correct with your swift response! Maybe you could help with [this extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23701180/replace-based-on-regex-and-return-manipulated-string) of this question? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) instead. It allows you to perform a search and replace using a callback function:

```
echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($m) {
    return strtotime($m[0]);
}, $my_string);
```

`$m` is the array containing the matched items. `$m[0]` contains the date string.

The above code would output:

```
Hello world 1419501600 and foo 1410325200, bar
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/152163)

Comment: Exactly what I was missing, thank you very much for the quick response!