# Replace based on regex and return manipulated string

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have a logic query as a string, for example:

> mydate == 'one day ago' && mydate > 2014-05-16 16:00:00

I need every instance of a date replaced by a timestamp. My current code can replace the `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` date-time to a timestamp using `strtotime()`:

```
$my_string = "mydate == 'one day ago' && mydate > 2014-05-16 16:00:00";

// Pattern: *YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS*
$pattern = '((?:2|1)\\d{3}(?:-|\\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(?:-|\\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[1-2][0-9])|(?:3[0-1]))(?:T|\\s)(?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:2[0-3])):(?:[0-5][0-9]):(?:[0-5][0-9]))';

$my_string = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($m){return strtotime($m[0]);}, $my_string);

echo($my_string);
```

Output:

> mydate == 'one day ago' && mydate > 1400252400

However, I also want to support natural language relative phrases. The query string is always of a set structure:

> mydate `OPERATOR` '`DATE`' && mydate `OPERATOR` '`DATE`'...

What I'd like to do is find the variable `mydate` skip past the operator then get the contents within the single quotes, apply `strtotime()` to the contents of the single quotes and then replace the date (including single quotes) with the integer. For example:

Input:

> mydate == 'one day ago' && mydate > '2014-05-16 16:00:00'

Target process:

> mydate == `timetostr('one day ago')` && mydate > `timetostr('2014-05-16 16:00:00')`

Output:

> mydate == 123123123123 && mydate > 1400252400

Note the difference between my current and the new input, now I want both instances to have single quotes and not use a regex designed only for date-time strings.

How can I make a regex along the lines of
    variable_name*'*'

Where * is any character, take the contents of '*' and return variable_name**

Comment: What is the final goal of all of this?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte to run the logic/query resulting in true or false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:
`[^\-+\*=]+\s*[\-+\*=]{1,2}\s*('[^']+')\s*\&\&`
([regex101](http://regex101.com/r/lS6kV8))

The first character class is any non-operator character 1 or more times, then 0 or more whitespace characters, then 1 or 2 operator characters (you may or may not want to include angle brackets here) then 0 or more whitespace characters then you capture the `'*'` as you've termed it above.

Comment: Adam, thank you very much for your response and the extremely helpful link! I've actually learnt quite a lot about regex from that resource and your example and I think I've got enough to work with now. I even understand what it means now, it's high time I became fluent in regex. Much appreciated.

Comment: You're very welcome.  Another really good regex resource: [RexEgg](http://www.rexegg.com),

Answer (score 0):

I have settled with this based on information on @adamdc78's link

```
$str = "mydate == '1 day ago' && mydate != '2014-05-16 16:00:00' && myname = 'Craig' || mydate > '2014-05-16 16:00:00'"; 

$var_name = 'mydate';

$re = '/'.$var_name.'\s*[\-+\=\<\>\!]{1,2}\s*(\'[^\']+\')/'; 

$my_string =    preg_replace_callback(
                    $re,
                    function($m)
                    {
                        foreach($m as $key=>$value)
                        {
                            $m[0] = str_replace('\'','',$m[0]);
                            $m[1] = str_replace('\'','',$m[1]);
                            $m[0] =     str_replace($m[1],strtotime($m[1]),$m[0]);
                        }

                        return($m[0]);
                    },
                $str
                );

echo($my_string);
```

Output

> mydate == 1400245345 && mydate != 1400252400 && myname = 'Craig' || mydate > 1400252400